# Power BI Bing Maps not showing all locations

Tags: location, powerbi, bing-maps

I’ve created a rapport which shows population and household statistics Per Zip Code in the Netherlands.

At the moment I run into a problem, where Powe BI Bing Maps doesn’t show all the locations.

Is there a max number of locations Power BI will allow me to locate on the map, since this mapping has over 4.000 locations, and 3 columns of data. (Population, amount of owned households & amount og renter households.

The way I have located the Zip Codes on the map, is by adding “, the Netherlands” after all of the Zip Codes.

Is there somehow a way for me to bypass the abovementioned problem?

Thank you in afvande for your assistance :)

Best regards
Patrick

Answer (score 3):

The max number of [data points for the map is 3500](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-data-points). You might consider switching the type of map visual you are using. Here are limits for other maps found in that same link:

- Filled chloropleth map: 10,000
- Shape map: 10,000
- ArcGIS map using address information in the Location field: 1,500
- ArcGIS map using a standard administrative value in the Location field: 15,000

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-map-tips-and-tricks) provides tips to improve geocoding. It suggests:

- Set the data category on your geography columns
- Rather than concatenating zip code and country into a single field, add both the zip code and country to your map as separate fields (drill down to the zip code level to get your original results).